# Possibility that two students answer the same on a 25 question multiple choice test

Tags: probability, average

I am trying to get some approximation of the possibility that two students would answer $25$ questions in a row exactly the same.  There are 4 possible responses for each question.  I calculate the random possibility as $4^{25}=1.13\times10^{15}$. Since, however, I assume some amount of familiarity with the material, I divided that by $4$.  I imagine, however, that this is not a precise method.  If I assume an average score of $60%$, is there a more precise model to determine the probability?

Comment: It really depends on the test. For example, lots of multiple choice tests have some answers which are easier to eliminate than others, or have wrong answers that are "bait" because they are close to right. It really can only be estimated if you  had enough data on people who took the test.

Comment: In real classrooms, it happens a lot, without collusion.

Comment: Dividing by $4$ is more or less the same as the assumption "there was one question on which both were sure of the (same) answer." I'm not a teacher, but that assumption seems a little pessimistic.

Answer (score 2):

While you can come up with a mathematical answer. It would only show how unlikely the possibility of the two students getting the same answers assuming they were to randomly guess. In reality, it is not as unlikely as you would think. For example some questions might have a really deceptive choice and both students pick that choice. Their was a trig test in my Algebra 2 Trig class where two students both failed the test with a score of a 43 and had the same exact answers as each other. Does this prove they cheated? No, they both had their calculators in radians instead of degrees and answered every question correctly. Yes, while mathmatically you can calculate the probability of two students getting the same answers with an average score of 60, but I would advise against it. Just because they have the same answers doesn't mean they cheated...If thats what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Basically, students with the same level of knowledge and skill will be expected to answer the questions in roughly the same pattern - which is *not* entirely randomly.  (Randomness only comes from lack of confidence.)  When the students are educated from the same curriculum, having similar knowledge bases is hardly in itself evidence of collusion.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I agree with you a 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Simply assuming the average score is not enough. For example, take a look at the following test:

1. Question $1$: What is $1+1$?
2. Question $2$: Prove conclusively that $P=NP$.

This test will have an average score of $50\%$, and the number of students that answer the same on all questions will be equal to the number of students taking the test.

On the other hand, you can ask a multichoice question about differential equations to a set of $6$ year old children. In that case, you can more or less assume that the answers are randomly distributed.

Comment: OP says that the test is multiple choice, so I think the calculation is valid.

Comment: @cuniculus I can think of a multiple choice test in which the calculation is still invalid. For example, go to the year 1300 and ask the multi-choice test with 2 questions: the first being "what is $1+1$?" and the other being "Does the earth rotate around the sun?"

Comment: You are saying you can construct a MC question which everyone will certainly get right or wrong (or to a lesser extent, questions which have a high probability of being right or wrong). I agree, and so the question is technically unanswerable, but I think this is a complication beyond the spirit of the OP (e.g. "I calculate the *random* possibility"). We can answer the question if we assume that each question has a 60% likelihood of being answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: We can calculate the probability if we assume that each question has a 60% likelihood of being correctly answered by either student.

For each question, the odds that the students will both choose the correct answer is $.60 \times .60=.36$. In this case, their answers will coincide. The odds that one student chooses the correct answer and one doesn't is $2 \times .60 \times .40 = .48$. In this case, their answers will not coincide. The odds that neither will choose the correct answer is $.40 \times .40 = 0.16$, in which case (assuming their choice is random) the odds that they will have the same guess is $1/3 = .333$. So, the odds per question that the guesses will coincide is $.36\times1 + .40\times0 +.16*.333 = .413$.

Now we want to know the odds that they guess the same for 25 questions; this is $.413^{25} = 2.5 \times 10^{-10}$.